# Generating a method for each subtype within a module

Tags: module, julia, metaprogramming

(Reposted from Julia slack for posterity)

let’s say I have some constants like

```
const FooConst = 1
const BarConst = 2
```

and I also have some struct

```
struct Foo end
struct Bar end
```

and I now want to define a method for each struct to look up that constant

```
f(::Type{Foo}) = FooConst
f(::Type{Bar}) = BarConst
```

how would I achieve that last block using metaprogramming? I'm essentially trying to tack on `Const` to the end of the name of the Struct and look that up in the code

...

...(this) works outside of a module, but in my module the constants aren't exported. After I import my module, f isn't able to look the constants up. MWE here:

```
module M
import InteractiveUtils: subtypes
export Foo, Bar, f

abstract type Super end
struct Foo <: Super end
struct Bar <: Super end

const FooConst = 1
const BarConst = 2

for T in subtypes(Super)
    @eval f(::Type{$T}) = $(Symbol(T, "Const"))
end

end # module
```

and then in my REPL:

```
julia> using Main.M
julia> f(Foo)
ERROR: UndefVarError: Main.M.FooConst not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] f(::Type{Foo}) at ./none:11
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

I am however able to access it directly:

```
julia> Main.M.FooConst
1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Mason Protter on Julia slack:

Mason Protter 2:26 PM
@Sebastian Rollen The issue was the `Symbol(T, "const")`. That actually ended up expanding to `Symbol("Main.Foo.FooConst")` and `Symbol("Main.Foo.BarConst")` instead of `Symbol("FooConst")` and `Symbol("BarConst")` respectively. You can fix that using `Symbol(nameof(T), "Const")` as shown here:

```
module M
import InteractiveUtils: subtypes
export Foo, Bar, f

abstract type Super end
struct Foo <: Super end
struct Bar <: Super end

const FooConst = 1
const BarConst = 2

for T in subtypes(Super)
    @eval f(::Type{$T}) = $(Symbol(nameof(T), "Const"))
end

end # module

julia> using .M;  f(Foo)
1

julia> f(Bar)
2
```

Make sure you restart Julia before running this code or Julia will continue to use the exported functions from the old version of your module.